# Script doesn't trash custom post types. Instead it duplicates the post and generate new versions in the trash

Tags: custom-post-types, trash

I've a function which deletes custom post types after a specific time. In my case after 30 days. The problem is, that the posts are not trashed. Instead WordPress creates a new version of the post with new ID and moves this new version in the trash. The status of the old version is still "published".

I delete posts with `wp_trash_post()`. I tried do delete them permanently with `wp_delete_post()`. The proble is, that wp_delete_post only works with native post types and not with custom post types.

And there is something strange... The function worked very well for a while and now it's broken?! Is it possible, that there is a bug in the new WordPress version (4.9)?

Here is the code of my function:

```
<?php
    function get_delete_old_jobs() {


    // WP_Query arguments
    $args = array(
        'fields'         => 'ids', // Only get post ID's to improve performance
        'post_type'      => array( 'post_type' ), //post type
        'posts_per_page' => '-1',//fetch all posts,
        'date_query'    => array(
            'before' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days'))
        )
    );

    // The Query
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // The Loop
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $query->the_post();

            $postid     = get_the_ID();
            $post       = get_post($postid);                

            // do something
            // ....
            // here I generate an e-mail for the author

            wp_mail($author->user_email, $subject, $message, $headers);

            wp_trash_post( $id );
            // also tried this version
            // wp_trash_post( $post_id );
        }
    } else {
        // no posts found
        return false;

    }

    // Restore original Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();

}

// expired_post_delete hook fires when the Cron is executed
add_action( 'old_job_delete', 'get_delete_old_jobs' );


// Add function to register event to wp
add_action( 'wp', 'register_daily_jobs_delete_event');

function register_daily_jobs_delete_event() {
    // Make sure this event hasn't been scheduled
    if( !wp_next_scheduled( 'old_job_delete' ) ) {
        // Schedule the event
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'old_job_delete' );
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: You’re not setting $post_id *or* $id. At least in the code you’ve posted.

Comment: Ah sorry, I accidentally deleted the line of code where I set the ID. And now I guess I've found my mistake... I'm settting `$postid` and using `$id` instead. Seems to work now. Thanks for the hint!!

Comment: If you want to add your answer about the correct use of the ID, I will accept it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$id` variable is never set. Use this instead:

```
wp_trash_post( $postid );
```